# D3js labels on grouped bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to put labels on my d3js grouped bar chart, which is supposed to be easy, but I haven't been able to do it correctly. I know it must be similar to the way I'm adding the rects but no.. I tried to follow  [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32761032/d3-how-to-add-labels-top-of-in-each-bar-in-grouped-bar-chart) but it didn't work.

This is how I add my rectangles:

```
var rectG = pp.selectAll('rect')
  .data(dataFilter);

rectG.exit().remove();

var  rectGEnter= rectG.enter().append("g")
    .append("g")
      .attr("transform", function(d) {return "translate(" + x(d.group) + ",0)"; })
    .selectAll("rect")
    .data(function(d) { return subgroups.map(function(key) {return {key: key, value: d[key]}; }); })
    .enter().append("rect")
       .attr("x", function(d) { return xSubgroup(d.key); })
       .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value? d.value : 0); })
       .attr("width", xSubgroup.bandwidth())
       .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value? d.value : 0); })
       .attr("fill", function(d) { return getColor(d.key); })
```

so I tried to do the same with the lables but didn't work, except for this:

```
rectGEnter= rectG.enter().append("g")
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {return "translate(" + x(d.group) + ",0)"; })
  .selectAll("text")
  .data(function(d) { return subgroups.map(function(key) {return {key: key, value: d[key]}; }); })
  .enter().append("text")
     .attr("x", function(d) { return xSubgroup(d.key)+1; })
     .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value? d.value : 0); })
     .attr("text-anchor", "start")
     .style("alignment-baseline", "middle")
     .text(function(d) { return (d.value? d.value : 0); });

  }
```

and if ok for the first time, but if I update my data the labels don't update well, I haven an example [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/1DvXRt32z8pVcuCg), any help will be apreciate

Answer (score 1):

If I understand right you only want to remove the old labels. I tried it in you plunker. The following line of code does the trick.

```
 function updates(selectedGroup) {
    pp.selectAll("rect").remove();
    pp.selectAll("text").remove(); // <-- remove the old text elements
...
```

**EDIT**:

To prevent the removal of the labels we can simply add a class to specify which text we want to remove.

```
rectGEnter= rectG.enter().append("g")
      .append("g")
        .attr("transform", function(d) {return "translate(" + x(d.group) + ",0)"; })
      .selectAll("text")
      .data(function(d) { return subgroups.map(function(key) {return {key: key, value: d[key]}; }); })
      .enter().append("text")
        .attr('class', 'valueLabels') // <-- Here we add a class
         .attr("x", function(d) { return xSubgroup(d.key)+1; })
         .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value? d.value : 0); })
         .attr("text-anchor", "start")
         .style("alignment-baseline", "middle")
         .text(function(d) { return (d.value? d.value : 0); });
```

Now we can specify the class when removing the elements.

```
 function updates(selectedGroup) {
    pp.selectAll("rect").remove();
    pp.selectAll('g').selectAll('g').selectAll("text.valueLabels").remove(); // <-- remove the old text elements
...
```

Comment: it removes the y axes labels too